# Does Raspberry Pi OS support encryption on the RPI 1 WITHOUT extra hardware?

Tags: security, raspberry-pi, raspbian, encryption, privacy

I have a RPI 1. The original.

It is crucial for me, for basic bottom-line security, that all my machines are encrypted and cannot be booted/read once powered off without somebody entering the right password.

I cannot use my RPI for its purpose before I can be sure that I can easily enable encryption of its "disk" (flash card).

Is there a simple command that I can use once I have it running, to encrypt it and start requiring me to enter a password, just like I do with my normal PC and VeraCrypt (previously TrueCrypt)?

It must **not** require some hardware "security module"!

It doesn't matter if it becomes "too slow" as I find the non-encrypted RPI 1 to be more than powerful enough to power my system. It is not going to have a screen connected. It's going to be performing light "server" tasks with no real need to be "fast". Of course, if it becomes so slow that it takes 30 minutes to boot it up and it cannot calculate 1 + 1 without crawling on its knees, that *does* become a problem, but I have a feeling that such is not quite the case!

While I'm asking, I also wonder if this in any way is different if this had been a RPI 4? Surely it must still use the same command regardless of the RPI version, only later models are much faster?

Is the RPI 1 fundamentally *unable* to do this somehow?

Please don't link to one of those mile-long "tutorials" full of commands. I want to just do:

```
encrypt-pi
Please enter password: **********************
Working... 1%...
Working... 50%...
Working... 97%...
Done! Reboot now to enter the password and enter encrypted mode? y
Rebooting...
```

If this is not possible, what exactly stops this from being a thing? Am I really the only person who worries about thieves and other snoops stealing my RPI and thus getting hold of my entire customer database and records for my commercial project, etc.? I would even want this for a "media center" RPI; I might be showing private photos or videos in the living room which I don't want external people to see/have.

I find that whenever I ask about encryption anywhere, people just seem uncomfortable or perhaps unwilling to answer clearly. I hope this isn't the case this time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Debian, the distribution Raspbian is derived from, does support an encrypted disk.

But changing an unencrypted disk to an encrypted disk is not as easy as you are hoping.  I think you are going to need to backup and restore your filesystem.

(I'm running some experiments... will let you know.)

Edit: Experiments complete, successful, and not as easy as you are hoping.

In the description below, I am using `/dev/physicaldisk`, `encryptedname`,  `654321`, and `/backup/location` as placeholders.  The first is your existing device name (and might have different names in the PI and in another linux device to do most of the setup).  The second is a logical name to be applied to the encrypted disk.  The third is the size reported in step 2.  The fourth is somewhere to store the image of the filesystem (but not on filesystem being encrypted).

1. You will need to install cryptsetup and cryptsetup-initramfs (if available)
2. Start by shrinking your existing filesystem:

   ```
   fsck -f /dev/physicaldisk
   resize2fs -M /dev/physicaldisk
   ```

   This will report a new size, I'm going to write it as 654321 below.  Make sure you get it right.
3. Backup the existing filesystem to another location.

   ```
   dd if=/dev/physicaldisk of=/backup/location bs=4096 count=654321
   ```
4. Setup encryption on the disk, and open it.  This destroys what was there

   ```
   cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/physicaldisk
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/physicaldisk encryptedname
   ```
5. Restore the filesystem.

   ```
   dd if=/backup/location of=/dev/mapper/encryptedname bs=4096 count=654321
   ```

   If /backup/location is on a filesystem, you can safely omit the bs= and count= options.
6. Resize the restored filesystem to use all the space:

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/mapper/encryptedname
   ```
7. Modify the root filesystem entry in the bootloader.  For a PI, this would be in `config.txt`, I think in entry `cmdline`.  I think you need to change:

   ```
   root=/dev/physicaldisk
   ```

   to

   ```
   root=/dev/mapper/encryptedname cryptopts=target=encryptedname,source=/dev/physicaldisk
   ```

I think that should be it.  Try booting.

For a Raspberry PI, if you have two Micro-SD cards and can mount them both at once, you can skip /backup/location and go from the physical disk on one card to the encrypted filesystem on the other card.

Caveat: I tested this on a debian amd64 laptop, not a raspbian PI.  Your milage may vary.